# Where can i find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll for TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I`m building an extension for Visual Studio Team Explorer and a line of code like this:

```
ITeamExplorer teamExplorer = GetService<ITeamExplorer>();
```

needs a reference to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll`

which i couldn't find any where in TFS2015

Comment: Which paths have you tried?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

i also searched the whole C drive and couldnt find it

Comment: What's your detail  edition of VS2015?

Answer (score 3):

I have VS 2015 Pro installed. Found it at

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer**Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll

Comment: For VS 2017. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer` . Change 2017 to 2019 for VS2019. Also change `Enterprise` to your IDE type (e.g. `Community`, `Preview`, etc)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Visual Studio 2015 installed you should be able to find it at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll`; at least, that's where it is on my machine.

Also, I'm not sure if it's required, but I also have the Visual Studio Extensibility Tools installed, which is one of the optional items listed during the installation of Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You can  search  and find it under this path：**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions**

I found it under  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\mcjvkcdg.wd1  on my dev machine.